# Scheme problem with 'let'

Tags: function, scheme

I am trying to write a scheme program to read in 2 numbers and display their addition, but am having problem with the 'let' expression

```
(define (add-two)
  (let* ((first ((display "Enter first number:")
                (read)))
        (second ((display "Enter second number:")
                 (read))))
        (sum (+ first second))
        )
    (display "total is " sum)
    )
```

After reading the first number, the program crashes...and points to the let expression, the compiler reports

> 'procedure application: expected
>   procedure, given: #; arguments
>   were: 4'

I'm not sure how to fix this..What do you think is wrong?

thanks in adv!

Comment: You haven't told us what goes wrong.

Comment: okay, i've explained the error i get in more detail, thanks bmargulies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a mismatched set of parentheses. Try:

```
(define (add-two) 
  (let* ((first (begin
                  (display "Enter first number:") 
                  (read))) 
         (second (begin
                   (display "Enter second number:") 
                   (read)))
         (sum (+ first second)))
    (display "total is " sum)))
```

In the `let*` form, the first parentheses group the new bindings together, then the rest of them (just `display` in this example) is the body. In general:

```
(let* ((a1 x1) (a2 x2) ...) body ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in `let`, but in **procedure application**. Look at your first let expression:

```
(first ((display "Enter first number:")
                 (read)))
```

You try to bind to the symbol `first` result of expression `((display "Enter first number:") (read))`. I understand you expect this will do 2 actions: display message and read input, but it will not. First expression (i.e. `(display "Enter first number: ")`) will be evaluated to `void#`. Second expression will give an input. After 2 arguments will be evaluated, Scheme will see an expression `(void# 4)`. But this a procedure application! And Scheme tells you about it with your error message.

To avoid this you can do 2 things: show message *before* `let` expression:

```
(define (add-two) 
   (display "Enter first number:")
   (let (first (read))
      (display "Enter second number:")
      (let second (read))
         ...
```

Or use `begin` procedure to evaluate expressions sequentially:

```
(define (add-two)
   (let* ((first (begin (display "Enter first number:")
                        (read)))
          (second (begin (display "Enter second number:")
                         (read))))
          ...
```